# What are the Magento2 code formating settings for PHPStorm?

Tags: magento2, phpstorm

When editing Magento2 .phtml files, it would be nice to use the code formating function of PhpStorm, but without changing the original layout (just format added stuff).

So did anybody already set up PHPStorm's format settings for Magento2 and would like to share them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento 2 team use [PSR1/PSR2 code styles](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html) (in PHPStorm: preferences > Code Style > PHP > set from > PSR1/PSR2) and verify it with static test [Magento\Test\Php\LiveCodeTest::testCodeStylePsr2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/LiveCodeTest.php#L98)

Answer (score 1):

Basically it seems to be ident = 4 spaces. But they sometimes align the equals signs:

```
<?php $_option = $block->getOption(); ?>
<?php $_selections  = $_option->getSelections(); ?>
<?php $_default     = $_option->getDefaultSelection(); ?>
<?php list($_defaultQty, $_canChangeQty) = $block->getDefaultValues(); ?>
```

This looks wrong to me, as it is not consequent and should be fixed.

Comment: You're correct, space aligning is acceptable, but should either be applied consistently or not at all.